# Random implementation of methods in cocos2d-iphone?

Tags: ios, random, cocos2d-iphone

I have some "void" methods in my project using cocos2d-iphone and would like make them random. Unfortunately, I'v found only little information about genareting random numbers. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to call a random method, right?
Get your method signatures in an array:

```
NSArray* methods = @[@"myMethod1", @"myMethod2", @"myMethod3"];
```

Pick a method name:

```
NSString* method = methods[arc4random()%method.count];
```

Call it:

```
[self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(method)];
```

It would be also wise to check that self can respond to that selector first.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Try this

 .h

-(int) randomGenarete;

 .mm

-(int) randomGenarete
{

int random_number = arc4random() % 100;  // return random 0 to 99
return random_number;

}
```

Comment: Well, it just generates a random number. I want mix methods?